# Considering User Accessibility when developing a mobile application

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, accessibility

Is it necessary to include a wide variety of user accessibility features such as color contrast or different font sizes?

Since modern smartphones are capable of catering to users with Visual, Hearing and other types of disabilities within their base settings then is it worth putting in accessibility features in-case of a scenario where users don't know about said features on their phone?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the possibility that users **do not know about these settings.** In that case, it does not harm to tell them **how they could change** their phone settings.

Sometimes, it depends on the app that you are building. For example if your app contains too many colors, it might not be color-blind proof. One of my all time favorite apps - Two dots - has the following functionality. I am not color-blind, but I still use this feature sometimes when there is too much light and I cannot distinguish the colors easy.

[image: two-dots]

Comment: I think that Two Dots example (which as a game I love) is an example of poor design. Why should a colourblind person be forced to have a different experience to everyone else? What about inclusive design?

Comment: @Midas I am really interested to hear your suggestions! It is a subject that I find very interesting!